# Scope of variable in WebSQL

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I have this function

```
const _getCountriesByContinentCode = continent_code => {
    const someDb = SQLite.openDatabase(db);
    let foo = [];
    someDb.transaction(tx => {
        tx.executeSql("SOME SQL", [], (tx, results) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                foo.push((results.rows.item(i)));
            }
            console.log('####', foo) // this logs the result as expected
        });
    });
    console.log('****', foo) // this does not log the pushed result, but an empty array 
}
```

The `console.log('####', foo)` logs as expected the results of `foo.push(...)`. However, the `console.log('****', foo)` logs an empty array.

Why is that? Is `someDb.transaction(...` asynchronus?

Comment: Yes it is, and `tx.executeSql` is also definitely asynchronous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, as @Bergi suggest in the comment below the Q: `SQL.transaction` and `SQL.executeSql` are both asynchronous.